# crystal reports: how to compare multiple rows of data

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal report that is showing the following:

```
ACT Status
987 Blank
987 received
987
252 Blank
252 received
475 Blank
522 Received
```

I would like the report to evaluate by ACT if the status has been received on any of the matching act lines dont show. If the status is Blank and not received then show

It would look like:

```
475 Blank
```

Comment: didn't understand what is your problem... explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide that row which is containing ACT Status not received then you can do that as.

place following code in detail section suppress formula

```
instr(fieldOrVariable, "received")>0
```

if status displays '0 received' when ACT not received. then you can check like this.

```
instr(fieldOrVariable, "0 received")>0
```